# Can you use "even so" without a comma before it?

Tags: word-usage

Can we use *even so* without a period (.) before it?

For example:

> There were minutes left to the deadline, even so we refused to panic.

Comment: 'Even so' is here an introductory element that fronts the main clause 'we refused to panic'. With the comma, you have a classic comma splice, one I'd avoid at all costs. At least a semicolon is needed here, and I'd probably upgrade to an ellipsis or a full stop and new sentence.

Comment: You don't want heavy punctuation here. A semi-colon would be heavy enough, or just a dash.

Comment: You need a coma after *even so* and a period, semicolon, or em dash before.